# Apply style to feature after adding it to layer Source

Tags: openlayers, style

I am trying to apply style of my newly created feature which I add programatically to already defined vectorSource.

```
scope.tempSource = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX:false});

scope.drawingVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: scope.tempSource,
                zIndex: 10,
                style: gaStyleFactory.getStyle('airbusBbox')
            });
```

Every drawed feature gets that style, also when I select feature, it applies selectStyle which is defined in my selectInteraction:

```
scope.addSelectInteraction = function() {
                var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
                    layers: function(lyr) {
                        return (lyr === scope.drawingVectorLayer);
                    },
                    style:gaStyleFactory.getStyle('select')
                });
```

I add my feature this way:

```
scope.tempSource.addFeature(uploadedKmlFeature);
```

My assumption was that it will inherit style from vector layer in which it's appended. I was wrong . Still feature can be selected and its visible inside **selectInteraciton.getFeatures()** but no style is applied. Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: The KML import can set styles (either extracted from the KML or Google defaults styles) directly on featues which will override layer and interaction styles.  Try calling `uploadedKmlFeature.setStyle()` to clear them.

Comment: Yes it works now , thank you !!